# Do something when touch on anything other than a specific view in Android

Tags: android, onclick, ontouchlistener, floating-action-button

There is a floating action button (FAB) in the screen, with one click expanding/collapsing. The designed behavior is, when the FAB is expanded, if the user touch/click on anywhere other than the expanded FAB, the FAB should collapse. e.g. if I click the main screen, or click the sidebar menus, or the action bar / toolbar, the FAB should collapse. How should I design this pattern?

I don't want to list all other views in my code and set the onTouchListener on them.

I'm thinking setting an observer or watcher on the screen, once the FAB is expanded, the observer will be established to observe the NEXT touch: if the next touch is not happened on the expanded FAB, just call method `collapseFab()`. However, I don't know how should I implement this in Android, and how to set such an observer on the whole screen...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap FAB in a `FrameLayout` and make this `FrameLayout` full screen and above all view in Acitivy. When your FAB is expanded, set `OnClickListener` to this `FrameLayout`, and when your FAB is collapsed, remove `OnClickListener`. With that way, you can handle click event outside FAB.

Comment: With this strategy, if I click other views when FAB is expanded, nothing will happen except the FAB will be collapsed. However, I expect that behaviors of clicking on other views will not been blocked. e.g. If I click on the sidebar menu, it should open the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (mFloatingMenu.isExpanded()) {

        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        mFloatingMenu.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);

        if(!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY()))
            mFloatingMenu.collapse();
    }
}

return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
```

}

Use this code to complete your operation.

Refer https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/issues/204